# Tosca element locator got problem while x-scanning link or button attribute

Tags: scanning, tosca

I am exploring the Tricentis Tosca trial version and I facing a problem while scanning the home page of http://sampleapp.tricentis.com/, I took one attribute that is automobile Link And I add that in my module. I see that the location of my link attribute is somewhere else But the actual link attribute is on another place in X-scan.
Any One an idea about this. 
[tor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vUDW8.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vUDW8.png)

Answer (score 0):

We have similar issue, after we ensure the browser set as 100%, problem resovled, see https://documentation.tricentis.com/en/1000/content/tbox/xbrowser.htm for details.

Comment: Please write a summary of the link here as it will make the answer easier to evaluate for a future reader.